# Existence of certain function in Schwartz space

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose a polynomial $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is given. Does there exist a function $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that supp$(\phi)\subset\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}P(X)\phi(X)\,dX=0?$

notation:$\,\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$is the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^n,\,\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Schwartz space, and $X=(x_1,\cdots,x_n),\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to integrate over the sphere using surface measure (otherwise, if you integrate over $\mathbb R^n$, $\textrm{supp}(\phi)$ is measure zero).

In this case, let $\phi$ be any [spherical harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics). If $\int P\phi = 0$, you are done. Otherwise, let

$$
\psi = \phi - \frac{1}{|P|^2}\left(\int P\phi\right)P
$$

where $|P|^2 = \int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}P^2$. Assume for the moment that $\psi \neq 0$. Then

$$
\int\psi P = \int \phi P - \frac{1}{|P^2}\left(\int P\phi\right)\int P^2 = 0.
$$

If $\psi \equiv 0$, then $P = c\phi$ for some constant $c$. In this case, just choose $\tilde \psi$ to be any *other* spherical harmonic, and you will get the result (the spherical harmonics are orthogonal).